# Upper bounds for $NP$ based on $NEXP = EXP$

Tags: complexity-theory, nondeterminism

It's open whether $EXP = NEXP \to P = NP$ (the other direction can be shown by [padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_argument)).  My question: has there been any progress along these lines at all?  For example, can we show that $EXP = NEXP \to NP \subset SUBEXP$ (where $SUBEXP = \cap_{\epsilon > 0} 2^{n^\epsilon}$)?

Comment: Perhaps you will get more responses in cstheory.se.

Comment: this reminds me of [exponential time hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_time_hypothesis) which is probably "close/ related"...

Answer (score 1):

If someone has demonstrated that $EXP=NEXP\implies NP\subseteq SUBEXP$, then that guy has *unconditionally* proved a long-sought separation $P^{NP}\subsetneq NEXP$.

*Proof*: If $EXP\neq NEXP$, then obviously, $P^{NP}\neq NEXP$.

So assuming $EXP=NEXP$, the above statement gives us $NP\subseteq SUBEXP$. We have:

$$P^{SUBEXP}=SUBEXP$$

So, $P^{NP}\subseteq SUBEXP\subsetneq EXP$.$\blacksquare$